# How to fixed header with in table?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Hi all I want to fix (or) freez`thead` header on top and want to scroll `tbody` values only in table, as of now in table while scroll the page everything gets scrolled, but expecting to scroll only the `tbody` values ... [My Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FD9Hskj24uJLimu0XL3z?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="sryarnorder in sryarnorder.colorshades">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td> <input type="text" ng-model="sryarnorder.color" style="display:none;">
                   <div style="text-align:center;" ng-repeat="dyedyarnreferencenumber in dyedyarnreferencenumbers | filter:sryarnorder.color">
            <p>{{dyedyarnreferencenumber.shade}}</p>
        </div> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" ng-model="sryarnorder.color" style="display:none;">
               <div style="text-align:center;" ng-repeat="dyedyarnreferencenumber in dyedyarnreferencenumbers | filter:sryarnorder.color">
            <p>{{dyedyarnreferencenumber.buyers_reference}}</p>
        </div> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" ng-model="sryarnorder.color" style="display:none;">
                   <div style="text-align:center;" ng-repeat="dyedyarnreferencenumber in dyedyarnreferencenumbers | filter:sryarnorder.color">
            <p>{{dyedyarnreferencenumber.approved_supplier_ref}}</p>
        </div> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" ng-model="sryarnorder.color" style="display:none;">
                   <div style="text-align:center;" ng-repeat="dyedyarnreferencenumber in dyedyarnreferencenumbers | filter:sryarnorder.color">
            <p>{{dyedyarnreferencenumber.category}}</p>
        </div> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" ng-model="sryarnorder.color" style="display:none;">

            <p>{{sryarnorder.order_quantity}} {{sryarnorder.order_quantity_unit}}</p>
        </div> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" ng-model="sryarnorder.color" style="display:none;">

            <p>{{sryarnorder.price_per_kg_currency}} {{sryarnorder.price_per_kg}}</p>
        </div> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" ng-model="sryarnorder.color" style="display:none;">

            <p>{{sryarnorder.order_quantity * sryarnorder.price_per_kg}}</p>
        </div> </td>
    </tr>
```

**CSS**

```
table tbody, table thead
{
    display: block!important;
}

table tbody 
{
   overflow: auto!important;
   height: 100px!important;
}

table {
    width: 100%!important;
}
th
{
    width: auto!important;
}
```

**Data**

```
$scope.sryarnorders = [{"_id":"573d7fa0760ba711126d7de5","user":{"_id":"5721a378d33c0d6b0bb30416","displayName":"ms ms"},"__v":1,"colorshades":[{"_id":"573d7fc3760ba711126d7de6","price_per_kg_currency":"Inr","price_per_kg":"2","order_quantity_unit":"kg","order_quantity":"23","color":"56ffc46dab97a73d1066b792","quality":"Home Textiles","count":"yarn count"}],"created":"2016-05-19T08:56:00.997Z","remarks":"approved","actual_delivery_date":"2016-05-19","ex_india_date":"2016-05-19","ex_factory_date":"2016-05-19","lc_details_date":"2016-05-19","lc_details":"tooo much","po_delivery_date":"2016-05-19","sales_contract_date":"2016-05-19","sales_contract":"bioler","purchase_order_no_date":"2016-05-19","purchase_order_no":"1234","supplier_name":"Fsa","buyer_name":"e21"},{"_id":"56ffc6d5ab97a73d1066b798","user":{"_id":"56ff7bece2b9a1d10cd074a3","displayName":"saravana kumar"},"__v":1,"colorshades":[{"_id":"56ffc723ab97a73d1066b799","price_per_kg_currency":"Inr","price_per_kg":"120","order_quantity_unit":"kg","order_quantity":"25","color":"56ffc46dab97a73d1066b792","quality":"Home Textiles","count":"yarn count"}],"created":"2016-04-02T13:19:17.746Z","remarks":"pending","actual_delivery_date":"2016-04-02","ex_india_date":"2016-04-04","ex_factory_date":"2016-04-02","lc_details_date":"2016-04-02","lc_details":"lc","po_delivery_date":"2016-04-02","sales_contract_date":"2016-04-02","sales_contract":"required","purchase_order_no_date":"2016-04-02","purchase_order_no":"125","supplier_name":"Fsa","buyer_name":"Binary hand"},{"_id":"56ffc5e0ab97a73d1066b796","user":{"_id":"56ff7bece2b9a1d10cd074a3","displayName":"saravana kumar"},"__v":1,"colorshades":[{"_id":"56ffc608ab97a73d1066b797","price_per_kg_currency":"usd","price_per_kg":"5","order_quantity_unit":"kg","order_quantity":"20","color":"56ffc46dab97a73d1066b792","quality":"yarn quality","count":"yarn count"}],"created":"2016-04-02T13:15:12.876Z","remarks":"clear","actual_delivery_date":"2016-04-02","ex_india_date":"2016-04-02","ex_factory_date":"2016-04-02","lc_details_date":"2016-04-02","lc_details":"free","po_delivery_date":"2016-04-02","sales_contract_date":"2016-04-02","sales_contract":"required","purchase_order_no_date":"2016-04-02","purchase_order_no":"12345","supplier_name":"Fsa","buyer_name":"e21"}];
});
```

Comment: You can try sticky Header https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/oVlgM

Comment: I would rather suggest you to go with DIV blocks instead of table

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu

(you need to set fixed column widths)

**HTML:**

```
<table class="fixed_headers">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>These are red.</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- more stuff -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fixed_headers {
  width: 750px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.fixed_headers th {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.fixed_headers th,
.fixed_headers td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(1),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 200px;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(2),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(2) {
  min-width: 200px;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(3),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 350px;
}
.fixed_headers thead {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FDFDFD;
}
.fixed_headers thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.fixed_headers tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.fixed_headers tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.old_ie_wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 750px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.old_ie_wrapper tbody {
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer we will check and update you asap....if you have time please update my plunker as well....thanks

Comment: I have updated my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/FD9Hskj24uJLimu0XL3z?p=preview please check this, while scrolling the page the `thead` also getting scrolled, what i am expecting is the `thead` header should be fixed on top and `tbody` only should scroll........thanks, if possible please update my plunker ...

Comment: Please check your markup first. There are several issues which may be the reason why it won't work.
In case you don't know: It's not allowed to use any other elements than `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`, `tr`, `td`, `th`, `col`, `colgroup` inside of a `table`

Comment: thanks i know i were did a mistake in my markup, can you please update the solution, update my plunker as well to know the exact solution thanks...

Comment: I'd suggest you try it yourself, because:
1. I have no clue what your project is about
2. If you don't do it yourself, you will learn nothing from it